# Ubuntu 15.04 not booting after terminal upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-15.04

Ubuntu 15.04 shows the following error when I try to boot. This happened after a direct upgrade from 14.04.

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.

/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash

[ 5.668912] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to:

1. Boot from the installation medium (a USB? A CD?).
2. Open the terminal, and determine the partition on which your Linux system is hosted. Issue the command

   ```
   sudo parted
   ```

   and then, when the prompt appears,type <kbd>p</kbd>. This diplays the disk partition table. Your partition is neither the *swap* nor an the *extended* partition (**if** you have it, you might not have one). The partition you are interested in is the one with the *boot flag*. Let us assume it is */dev/sda1*. Quit `parted` by menas of <kbd>q</kbd>, then
3. issue the command

   ```
   sudo fsck /dev/sda1
   ```

   When done, give the command

   ```
   sudo shutdown -h now
   ```
4. Now remove the USB stick, and you should be able to boot normally.

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened still got the same error after booting...thanks for the help.